# Designing chat layout with Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextpane

I am trying to design a chat UI with Swing, but I am too dumb to figure out how to do proper indentation for the message portion.

Here's an example of what I'm after:
[image: http://xchat.org/docs/start/xchat-3-channel.png]

Here's what I just hacked together (just copy-and-paste it):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Scrap {

private static final int NICK_INDENT = 120;
private static final int MESSAGE_INDENT = NICK_INDENT + 10;

private static boolean applyHangingIndent = false;

public static void main(final String args[]) {
    StyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument();
    JTextPane pane = new JTextPane(doc) {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawLine(NICK_INDENT + 5, 0, NICK_INDENT + 5, getHeight());
        }
    };

    TabStop[] tabs = new TabStop[2];
    tabs[0] = new TabStop(NICK_INDENT, TabStop.ALIGN_RIGHT, TabStop.LEAD_NONE);
    tabs[1] = new TabStop(MESSAGE_INDENT, TabStop.ALIGN_LEFT, TabStop.LEAD_NONE);
    TabSet tabset = new TabSet(tabs);

    StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
    AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.TabSet, tabset);
    pane.setParagraphAttributes(aset, false);

    insertString(doc, "\ta nickname:\tthis is the message blaa blaa blaa\n");

    if (applyHangingIndent) {
        applyHangingIndent(doc);
    }

    insertString(doc, "\tanother nickname:\there is another message blaa blaa blaablaa, try to resize the window\n");

    if (applyHangingIndent) {
        applyHangingIndent(doc);
    }

    insertString(doc, "\ta third nickname:\tnow try to set the applyHangingIndent to true!\n");

    if (applyHangingIndent) {
        applyHangingIndent(doc);
    }

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setContentPane(new JScrollPane(pane));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(600, 300);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private static void insertString(StyledDocument doc, String str) {
    try {
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), str, null);
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void applyHangingIndent(StyledDocument doc) {
    SimpleAttributeSet sas = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    int indent = MESSAGE_INDENT;
    StyleConstants.setFirstLineIndent(sas, -indent);
    StyleConstants.setLeftIndent(sas, indent);
    doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), sas, false);
}
}
```

Try to resize the window to a smaller size.

Now, try to set the applyHangingIndent to true and resize again.

To my mind the code should be OK, however the negative first line indent property does not seem to work with tabstops.

Anyone have ideas how to make the indentation work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend another approach - tables based.

See the example http://java-sl.com/JEditorPaneTables.html and this http://java-sl.com/JEditorPaneTablesRowColumnInsert.html
You can define a table with 2 columns and as many rows as you need (for each message).

The first cell contains nickname and the second contains message. You can align content of cells (normal paragraphs in fact) as you wish. Also you can define any desired borders to be rendered or not for the columns/rows.

Comment: That sure looks like it would fit my needs very well, I'll start experimenting with your code. Thanks!

Comment: OK, after a few days of coding I got everything working just as I intended to. Thank you again for creating these clever tables!

Comment: Could you add an example code for creating the table with two rows? I'm completely lost in the referred code.

Comment: I'm quite curious: can I prevent the editability of the tables that are generated by the code?

Comment: Of course you can. Add a DocumentFilter and check whether offset past in the table bounds. if yes just ignore the edit